# How to extract information meeting a specific criterion from a table?

Tags: matlab, filter, grouping, spreadsheet, matlab-table

I have a table with 6 columns and 140,000 rows, and I can't figure out how to extract specific information from the table. For instance, when I try to extract all the accidents that happens on a specific date, either it tells me that the row `'12/05/2015'` does not exist or it doesn't let me set `'Date'` as a Row Name since the dates repeat because more than one accident happens in a day, thus giving me the error that `'Duplicate row name: '01/01/2015'`.

How can I pick a date and extract all of the data that corresponds to it?

P.S. Below you can see two photos, one of the table and one of the errors I get when trying to set date as a row to make everything clearer.

[image: Picture of table]

[image: Picture of error]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors, it's much less convenient to look at, than code ```` or a quotation (`> `). As for your problem, I think you should [group](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/split-table-data-variables-and-apply-functions.html) the table according to `Date` field and [continue from there](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/grouping-variables-for-splitting-data.html)...

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly your matter, you want to extract from the table, the rows that contain Date1, if so try this :

```
new_table = table(table(:,1)==Date1,:);
```